# Error en una consulta con Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

espero me puedan ayudar.

Tengo un pequeño proyecto en Laravel y quiero realizar una consulta a una sola tabla, en MySQL Workbench me sale bien la consulta, sin embargo cuando escribo la consulta con Eloquent me devuelve valores que no debería y la consulta es exactamente la misma.

Esta es mi consulta

```
SELECT * FROM productos
WHERE productos.filtro>productos.total;
```

Con Eloquent:

```
$producto=Producto::where('filtro','>','total')
                    ->get();
return $producto;
```

Cuando ejecuto mi consulta en MySQL Workbench me devuelve bien los resultados cuando el filtro es mayor al total. Pero con Eloquent no, devuelve incluso cuando el total es mayor al filtro. ¿Como lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: Así como lo muestras, estás comparando el valor de la columna 'filtro' con un string ('total'). ¿Lo que quieres es comparar el valor de la columna 'filtro' con el valor de la columna 'total'?

Comment: Así es, ambos valores son enteros en mi base de datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para comparar en un where los valores de dos columnas puedes usar [whereRaw()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions):

```
$producto = Producto::whereRaw('filtro > total')
                    ->get();
return $producto;
```

Comment: Con `whereRaw` no hay que pasar los 3 parámetros, el primero es directamente la consulta: `whereRaw('filtro > total')->get()`.

Comment: De esa forma quedo bien. Muchas gracias a ambos

Comment: @azeós es cierto, se me pasó eso, gracias!